# How to check if a sum/multiplication/subtraction creates overflow?

Tags: c

So I am just trying to add two numbers together,

The first one is `P1 = 2147483647` and the other is `P2 = 1`
This should overflow the type int so I wrote this to try to prevent the computer from doing the overflow

```c
if((P1 + P2) > sizeof(int)){
    halt = 1; /*halt is just a flag*/
}
```

But the computer obviously still tries to do the sum to check it, giving me a runtime error before the message I wrote that simply says that I cannot add those two number together. How can I do that without occurring into the runtime error and just displaying my message?

I am also trying to do this for a subtraction and multiplication but the problem is the same.

EDIT : I need to do this for a project, I don't think I can use the library limits.h

Comment: Your `sizeof(int)` is probably `4` and won't do what you want. Try something like `if (INT_MAX - P2 < P1)`

Comment: Probably the compiler can determines the overflow at compile time. You *should* include a complete a complete code  in your question.

Comment: sizeof(int) will return 4. Not the value it can store. You can check if an overflow occurs in a non standard way, using the overflow bit in flag register.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect unsigned integer multiply overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-do-i-detect-unsigned-integer-multiply-overflow)

Comment: If you're using gcc, it has built-in functions for detecting overflow: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <limits.h>
if (P2 > INT_MAX - P1) {
   printf("Overflow would occur\n");
}
```

### Explanation:

`INT_MAX - P1` is the biggest value you can add to `P1` without overflow.
If `P2` is bigger than that value, then it is too big, and overflow would occur.

---

If you need to check for an underflow as well, the math idea is the same:

```
if ( -P2 < P1 - INT_MIN) {
    printf("Underflow would occur\n");
}
```

### Explanation

`(P1 - INT_MIN)` is the biggest* value that could be subtracted from `P1` without underflowing.  If `-P2` is even more negative than that, then underflow would occur on addition.

* Biggest by magnitude, not by value.

Comment: What happens if both numbers are negative?

Comment: This might be helpful if i can actuallly use the library, but what about the subtraction? like, i need to do the same control for that, so how would you check if a number surpasses the inferior limit of int?

Comment: Why would you not be able to use `limits.h`?  You can certainly #define the values yourself if the include file is not available.

Comment: With p1=-1 you are producing yourself an overflow and the warning will appear often.

Answer (score 1):

A classical bit trick to test overflow is to compute:

```
if( (~(p1^p2) & (p1^(p1+p2)) & (1ull<<(8*sizeof(p1)-1)) ){
  printf("overflow in the addition of p1 and p2") ;
}
```

The idea if that overflow can only occur when both numbers are of the same sign. In this case, it can proofed that overflow will produce a number with a sign different from one of the argument. That is what check the function.
So on the MSB (last part of the expression), check if signs of operands are identical (first part of the expression) and if sign of the result is different from sign of operand 1 (second part of the expression).

For a substraction, it is sufficient to remove the bit complement in the expresion.

Comment: You rely on 32 bit integers. Consider to replace the constant with `(1<<(8*sizeof(p1)-1))`. When p1 and p2 are integer types of type int8_t the task becomes complicated due to integer promotion.

Comment: You're right. Fixed. For small ints, there should not be any problem as with the mask only the sign bit for the corresponding type is concerned..

Comment: You forgot the bits-per-byte shift factor of eight!

Comment: Ooops! Thanks for signalling.

Comment: Still wrong: `8  *  (sizeof(p1)-1)` --> `(8*sizeof(p1) - 1)`